# Ссылка, вызывающая активити

Tags: android

Нужно реализовать по такому принципу: есть текст допустим(TextView). Для дополнительной информации нажмите **сюда.**

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки сюда (будет как ссылка) открывалось новое активити?

Answer (score 1):

Сделать последнее слово в виде Button, задав свойство текст = "сюда", и `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 0):

Это пример с <u></u>. Думаю, можно нечто подобное сделать с <b></b>

```
<string name="clickable_string">Для дополнительной информации нажмите <u>сюда</u></string>

final Context context = ... ;// whereever your context is
CharSequence sequence = Html.fromSource(context.getString(R.string.clickable_string));
SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
UnderlineSpan[] underlines = strBuilder.getSpans(UnderlineSpan.class);
for(UnderlineSpan span : underlines) {
   int start = strBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
   int end = strBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
   int flags = strBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);
ClickableSpan myActivityLauncher = new ClickableSpan() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        context.startActivity(getIntentForActivityToStart());
    }
};
strBuilder.setSpan(myActivityLauncher, start, end, flags);
}

TextView textView = ...
textView.setText(strBuilder);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```